# C - GtkTextBuffer text with tag to gchar

Tags: sqlite, gtk3

I am currently learning about `GTKTextTags` and the application to `GtkTextView` and `GtkTextBuffer`. I did notice [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885552/need-example-help-with-gtktextbuffer-of-gtktextview-serialize-deserialize) but was not looking to export my data to a rich text file which I understood to be the main purpose of the question

I have an application which stores the contents of a `GtkTextBuffer` into a `TEXT` field of a `SQLITE3` database. Having read the [GtkTextWidget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TextWidget.html) Overview and the documentation on [GtkTextTag](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTag.html), I (mistakenly) understood that the tag system worked much like a mark up language such as XML/HTML.

I was under the impression (after setting the `&start` and `&end` `GtkTextIters`) when I called `gtk_text_buffer_get_text (...)` with `gboolean include_hidden_chars` set to `TRUE` I would essentially obtain a `gchar*` that would also include `GtkTextTags` so the string might look like `<b>some text</b>` (but obviously with `GtkTextTag` formatters not HTML). I realise now this is not the case.

**Problem:** I store the `gchar*` obtained from `gtk_text_buffer_get_text(...)` into the database `TEXT` field. At a later time, or when I reopen the application, I want to reload this data into the `GtkTextBuffer` and do so by retrieving the relevant `TEXT` field data from my database and setting text with `gtk_text_buffer_set_text (...)`. At this point I discover all of the formatting tags are gone and formatting somewhat becomes moot. What I would like to be able to do is store the text from the `GtkTextBuffer` into the `TEXT` field of the database and when it reloads the formatting is retained.

**Q: Is there a way to store both text and tags from a `GtkTextBuffer` into a SQLITE3 database so that when reloading this text to the `GtkTextBuffer` formating is retained?**

I had considered using a `BLOB` field rather than a `TEXT` field in the database but was uncertain if there is a better way to achieve what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`gtk_text_buffer_register_serialize_tagset()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-register-serialize-tagset) and then [`gtk_text_buffer_serialize()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-serialize) to get a byte array (`guint8[]`) that you can then read back into another text buffer later with `gtk_text_buffer_deserialize()`.

I think you will have to use a BLOB field rather than TEXT, since the return value of `gtk_text_buffer_serialize()` is a byte array rather than a string.

Comment: For fear of sounding stupid; what does serializing do ie. Is it simply changing the `gchar` to `guint8[ ]` or is there more going on than this?

Comment: There's more. Serializing means taking the entire contents of the buffer (including tags and I think even images) and outputting a form that is possible to write to disk, so that later when you deserialize you can restore the same contents of the buffer, including tags and images. It will be stored in a format that is internal to GTK.

Comment: At least, that's what the default serializer does. There exist other serializers, such as the RTF serializer in the answer that you linked above.

Comment: Ok thanks that's helpful. Having taken a look at the functions you recommended I've observed that to deserialize the data you require a `guint8` (the `BLOB`) and a `gsize` (the length of `BLOB`). My limited reading and understanding suggests these are compatible with `uint8` and `size_t`. To essentially reload the data to buffer I need to also store the gsize in the database.

Comment: Sqlite3 permits `int64` and a signed `int` but I think `gsize` is an 8 bite unsigned long which I'm assuming means it would fail to bind? To use another crude example is there a strlen()/sizeof() function (or way) to calculate the `gsize` of an `uint8`? or will I end up using another `BLOB` - (sorry a little off topic I know)

Comment: I don't know too much about sqlite3, but `gsize` is equivalent to `size_t` in the standard C types, which may be a different number of bytes on different machines. You could either store the size in two `int64` fields, or you could disallow text buffers whose serialized length was longer than `MAXINT64`.

Comment: (2/3) There is no such thing as a `strlen()` for byte arrays, because `strlen()` counts on there being a terminating 0 byte at the end of the string. The byte array may contain 0 bytes in the middle, that's why you're given an explicit length parameter.

Comment: (3/3) From my minimal understanding of the sqlite3 API it looks like you have to pass a length in when you create a blob, and the length looks to be an `int`. So you will have to disallow any buffers anyway that serialize to longer than `MAXINT` (or even explicitly `MAXINT32` if you want your databases to be portable between machines.)

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to convert safely from `size_t` to `int` which may offer a more simpler solution when binding and obtaining column data. My thought behind the `strlen()` equivalent would be essentially a `while()` function that scrolled through the byte aray byte by byte incrementing i++ leaving you with an `int` the size of the array at the end. I have no idea how big these arrays may be so it might be an impractical and resource demanding idea. I'm aware about the terminating `\0` with `strlen()` I was just trying to think of an example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found [the following](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=2300) resource with a (apparently) working example which was quite helpful from a reference to implementation GTK+ perspective. For anyone who later discovers this question It's worth noting it deals with exporting as a file rather than to an sql database.